# How to disable a programmatical breakpoint / assert?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, x86, assert, debugbreak

I am using Visual Studio, developing a native application, I have a programmatical breakpoint (assert) in my code placed using __asm int 3 or __debugbreak.  Sometimes when I hit it, I would like to disable it so that successive hits in the same debugging session no longer break into the debugger. How can I do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### x86 / x64

Assuming you are writing x86/x64 application, write following in your watch window:

x86: `*(char *)eip,x`

x64: `*(char *)rip,x`

You should see a value 0xcc, which is opcode for INT 3. Replace it with 0x90, which is opcode for NOP. You can also use the memory window with eip as an address.

### PPC

Assuming you are writing PPC application (e.g. Xbox 360), write following in your watch window:

`*(int *)iar,x`

You should see a value 0xfeNNNNNN, which is opcode for trap (most often 0x0fe00016 = unconditional trap). Replace it with 0x60000000, which is opcode for NOP.

Comment: on win32 you may have to make your code-segment writable. Great answer nevertheless!

Comment: I am doing this on Win32 and I have never seen any code-segment writeability issues. Can you elaborate some more? I will be glad to incorporate any more details into the answer to make it better.

Answer (score 4):

You might try something like this:

```
#define ASSERT(x) {\
   if (!(x)) \
   { \
      static bool ignore = false; \
      if (!ignore) \
      { \
         ignore = true; \
         __asm int 3 \
      } \
   }\
}
```

This should hit the debug only once. You might even show a messagebox to the user and ask what to do: continue (nothing happens), break (int 3 is called) or ignore (ignore is set to true, the breakpoint is never hit again)