# Prevent showing visual studio window when Breakpoint hits while debugging c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

When a breakpoints hits, the VS window is showed automatically and points to the line with the breakpoint. For my case that's not helping. Is it possible to prevent the VS studio window from showing when the breakpoint hits ? Thanks

EDIT: he problem is that I'm reading from a barcode scanner gun. While reading, the breakpoint hits thus switching to the VS window and some portion of the barcode is printed in the source file :) That's why I don't want it to switch to the VS window

Comment: What exactly do you want to do and why is it not helpful?

Comment: The breakpoint - is is a breakpoint set in the VS debugger, or a breakpoint in the code (using __debugbreak or asm int 3)?

Comment: OK. So you want the breakpoint to hit, the application to be stopped and the Visual Studio be ready, but not taking focus? To me this seems like something not possible.

Comment: @Suma , I was hoping there's some option in the visual studio about that.

Comment: Remote debugging is the standard solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the breakpoint in the Visual Studio, you can change it to "tracepoint" by specifying "Continue execution" as "When hit".

If the breakpoint is present in the executable, it can be disabled as described in [How to disable a programmatical breakpoint / assert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115237/how-to-disable-a-programmatical-breakpoint-assert/115238#115238)

Answer (score 0):

You can start your application as `Start Without Debugging` or use `(Ctrl + F5)` for that.

Or If you want to debug, but not for a condition, you can provide the condition on breakpoints when to hit.

Comment: I want to debug. The problem is that I'm reading from a barcode scanner gun. While reading, the breakpoint hits thus switching to the VS window and some portion of the barcode is printed in the source file :) That's why I don't want it to switch to the VS window